# keras tensorboard callbacks, no attribute '_should_trace'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to fit a DQN using keras-rl2 library. I believe the callbacks should work the same as training any neural network.

I want to visualise the training of the agent, and when I call the fit method to open tensorbaord to see its progress.

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='/keras-rl')
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=1200000, visualize=False, verbose=1, callbacks=[tb])


AttributeError: 'TensorBoard' object has no attribute '_should_trace'
```

I have searched for _should_trace errors, and cannot find any reference to it. Does someone know a workaround, or if I should structure my callback differently?

Comment: Downgrading to 2.3.2 seems to work. Have you found a way to fix the problem with 2.4.1?

Comment: I face the same issue on Tensorflow/-board 2.9.1

Comment: Same with tensorflow 2.12 why aren't they fixing this, it's been to long